# Is there any official/governmental website for cost of living in the US cities?

Tags: united-states, california, websites, government, cost-of-living

I am looking for a website that I can find cost of living in my city in California and refrence to it in my official claim. Is there any one?

Comment: I'd push back on this being off topic - they're not asking for a product, they're asking for *official government sources*, which feels like asking for an IRS ruling or similar - neither particularly likely to be outdated nor unreasonable to ask for.

Comment: I also I agree to reopen it.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service recommendations or **other off-site resources** are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."  We specifically edited this close reason to be clear that a question that is doing little more than looking for a link to a site is off topic. Sorry, I have a PF blog, and the IRS has been know to change their link structure. I've woken up to alerts of a hundred links breaking.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the  [GSA adjustment map](https://www.federalpay.org/gs/locality/san-francisco), which for example lists the Bay Area as 42.67% higher than the base pay. They have 53 rating areas. (Note: this linked map itself isn’t official, but it is using the official information.)

This likely understates the true cost of living difference, but it’s the best official government site I know of.

[OPM’s official tables](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/salary-tables/pdf/2022/saltbl.pdf) are also available, though less easy to use of course.